# How do I check if popcorn js fails to load a YouTube video?

Tags: javascript, youtube, popcornjs

I'm loading a YouTube video into popcorn.js. How do I check to see if it fails to load?

This is my current code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Create a popcorn instance by calling the Youtube player plugin
  var example = Popcorn.youtube(
    '#video',
    'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm1c2WTD93w&rel=0'
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on popcorn's media events [page](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/events/), they have an error event.  You can find out how to handle it in on the [utility methods page](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/utility-methods/#Popcorn.plugin.errors).